# Sign up policy UI

Tags: mobile, deletion

this is my first time writing here.

I am a newbie in the fieldm currently writing UI text for an APP in English.

I've been looking at these sentences for too long and now I don't know if they sound right or not. And I would very much appreciate your feedback.

They are error messages that pop up when you try to create a new account after deleting your previous one, but before the 30-day period.

> You can't sign up in less than 30 days since you deleted your account.

> You can create a new account after it's been over 30 days since you deleted your account.

Does this make clear sense? Or should I have said

"before 30 days have passed since.." or something like "You have to wait 30 days before you can ... "

I did do a google research, but I couldn't find anything similar.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

kitty,

Welcome to UX StackExchange.

I used to face similar problems, but then I realized that it's not about how long your sentences are. It's about conveying a clear message by setting a proper **context**.

There are 2 ways to do this.

1. Create a 2 part sentence, where you set the context in the first part and then convey the message in the second part.

   For example, "*You recently deleted your account. You can only create a new account after 30 days.*"
2. Create a nomenclature to set the context; like 'cool-down period'

   For example, "*You must complete 30 days cool-down period after deleting your account in order to create a new account.*"

Comment: Wow thanks so much Aditya !! !!

Comment: You are welcome @alpha-kitty
If you are satisfied with an answer and if it solves your problem then you can mark that answer as accepted by clicking on the tick mark against the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should clearly let them know why you are restricting them from creating a new account, for example:

**Account Sign-up Policy: 30 Days Threshold**

"New account creation requires a 30-day waiting period post-deletion"

OR

"Please wait for 30 days after account deletion to create a new account."

Also, if it's possible, show them the number of days already passed and the date on which they are able to sign up.

**24 days passed, you can create a new account after 29th July 2023**

**You are on day 21, wait 9 more days before you can signup again**